# Let $m$ be the least positive integer divisible by $17$ whose digits sum to $17$. Find $m$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $m$ be the least positive integer divisible by $17$ whose digits sum to $17$. Find $m$.

$m$ is a 3 digit number (because this was an AIME problem).

$$m \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$$

$$m \equiv 17 \pmod{9} \equiv -1 \pmod{9}$$

Applying the chinese remainder theorem, the solution is supposed to be:

$$m = 17 \cdot 9 = 153$$

but that isnt correct.

Comment: You have not applied the CRT correctly.  $153\equiv 0\pmod{9}$.  The correct answer to the CRT should be $17$; however this is not the answer to the problem.

Comment: Since $17$ is already $-1\mod{9}$, you want to add to it numbers that are multiples of both 17 and 9 until you get the number you want. It doesn't take long.

Comment: The correct answer is 476 if that helps.

Comment: $m\equiv 17\,$ both mod $17$ and $9$ $\iff 17,9\mid m\!-\!17\iff 17\cdot 9\mid m\!-\!17.$ CRT is not needed for that simple case.

Comment: $m \equiv 17 \pmod{17}$ is false. It is divisible by $17$?

Comment: @BillDubuque, I know but I would just like to know how to apply it for the future

Answer (score 2):

Lebes, from your lead and solving for $N$, we have
$$N \equiv 0 \pmod{17}\equiv 17 \pmod{17}$$
and from the digit sum condition
$$N \equiv 17 \pmod{9}.$$
Since $(17,9)=1$, we have $N\equiv17\pmod{153}$. [This uses principles from the Chinese Remainder Theorem - see the bottom for a detailed explanation]

Since this is only finding solutions where the digitsum $\equiv8\pmod{9}$, we now simply check the first few solutions to find the correct answer:

$1\times 153+17=170\longrightarrow $ digit sum  $=8\qquad$Nope.

$2\times 153+17=323\longrightarrow $ digit sum  $=8\qquad$Nope. [Fixed the error here]

$3\times 153+17=476\longrightarrow $ digit sum  $=17\qquad$Found it!

Therefore $N=476$.

Thanks @AaronMaroja for the correction.

---

Explanation of the use of CRT for @Amad27:

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve $N \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$ and $N \equiv 17 \pmod{9} \equiv 8 \pmod{9}$. Breaking these down we get $a_1=0$, $a_2=8$, $m_1=17$, $ m_2=9$, $M=m_1\times m_2=153$, $M_1=M/m_1=153/17=9$, $M_2=M/m_2=153/9=17$.

Now applying CRT we get
$$M_1y_1\equiv 1\pmod{m_1}\rightarrow 9y_1\equiv 1\pmod{17},$$
and
$$M_2y_2\equiv 1\pmod{m_2}\rightarrow 17y_2\equiv 1\pmod{9}\rightarrow 8y_2\equiv 1\pmod{9}.$$
It can be seen by observation that $y_1=2$ and $y_2=8$.

Finally, combining the above information we get
$$m=a_1M_1y_1+a_2M_2y_2=0\times9\times2+8\times17\times8=1088.$$
Since $1088\equiv17\pmod{153}$, we have
$$N\equiv m\pmod{M}\equiv17\pmod{153}$$

Comment: $2 \dot \, 153 + 17 = 323 \rightarrow $ digit sum $=8$.

Comment: How did you use the Chinese remainder theorem there?

Comment: @Amad27 I've expanded the above to explain the use of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: this answer is overkill.

Comment: @user31415 I'm just expanding on my previous one-liner on the CRT to fully explain how it comes about, as requested. It was more concise previously.

Comment: @Zac but the details show the process of how you used CRT. the thing is, the problem has an extremely short solution, and this is difficult compared to other solutions you could use. see my answer.

Comment: @user31415 I agree that there is a short solution, because my solution was short to begin with too. I mentioned in passing that it uses principles from the CRT, and I was asked to explain this. The answer may be overkill to you, but (I'm hoping) it isn't to the person who asked for elaboration.

Comment: @Zac shortness in terms of amount of words is not the determiner for whether a solution is overkill or not. Your solution is overkill because a fully explained application with every detail is long. My answer's fully explained application with every detail is short.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{cases}m\equiv 0\equiv 17\pmod {17}\\m\equiv 17\pmod{9}\end{cases}\implies 17, 9\mid m-17\stackrel{(17,9)=1}\implies 153\mid m-17$

So necessarily $m\in\{17,170,323,476,\ldots\}$. After checking $17,170,323,476$ in that order, only $476$ satisfies the sufficient conditions (of digits summing up to $17$). Answer: $476$.

This uses the hint by Bill Dubuque in the comments to op, so this answer is community wiki.